# Find Immediate Ancestor/Parent of a control

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, casting, parent-child

I have a `UserControl` named `AddressTemplate`, which contains a `StackPanel` with an assortment of `Labels` & `Textboxes`.  What I need is a way to find the immediate ancestor/parent of one of the controls within the `AddressTemplate`.  Essentially, I need a way to determine whether a given `Textbox` is inside the `AddressTemplate`, or instead is outside this `UserControl` and is just a standalone control.

What I've come up with so far is this:

```
private bool FindParent(Control target)
    {
        Control currentParent = new Control();

        if (currentParent.GetType() == typeof(Window))
        {

        }
        else if (currentParent.GetType() != typeof(AddressTemplate) && currentParent.GetType() != null)
        {
            currentParent = (Control)target.Parent;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;            
    }
```

The problem is, I keep getting an InvalidCastException because it can't cast a StackPanel as a Control.  Does anybody know the proper cast, or a viable way to fix this?

Comment: Sidenote: `new Control()` is redundant since you want to find an existing reference anyway.

Comment: I am not sure about how useful this approach would be but how about using a Tag property of a TextBox to store the parent information. If the TextBox is outside of usercontrol then the Tag will be null and if it is inside the AddressTemplate then you can directly cast it to StackPanel. (I am assuming that AddressTemplate is a StackPanel Control)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably want to use [`LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.logicaltreehelper.getparent.aspx) here, which returns a DependencyObject:

```
//- warning, coded in the SO editor window
private bool IsInAddressTemplate(DependencyObject target)
{
    DependencyObject current = target;
    Type targetType = typeof(AddressTemplate);

    while( current != null)
    {
       if( current.GetType() == targetType)
       {
          return true;
       }
       current = LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent(current);
    }
    return false;
 }
```

This would walk up the logical parent tree until it found no parent or the user control you are looking for.   For more info, look at [Trees in Wpf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753391.aspx) on MSDN

Comment: Works perfectly!  I did modify it a bit, making the `targetType` be passed in with the method call for re-usability, but other than that implemented it exactly like this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I use the extension method below, which creates an `IEnumerable` of all of the visual parents by walking up the visual tree:

```
public static IEnumerable<DependencyObject> VisualParents(this DependencyObject element)
{
    element.ThrowIfNull("element");
    var parent = GetParent(element);

    while (parent != null)
    {
        yield return parent;
        parent = GetParent(parent);
    }
}

private static DependencyObject GetParent(DependencyObject element)
{
    var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(element);

        if (parent == null && element is FrameworkElement)
            parent = ((FrameworkElement)element).Parent;

    return parent;
}
```

This is then pretty flexible.  In your example, you could use it as below:

```
if (target.VisualParents().OfType<AddressTemplate>().Any()) {
     //the target is in the address template
}
```